# How to make image comparison in openCV more coarse

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, image-processing, raspberry-pi

I am writing a code on raspberry pi in python to compare two images using mean squared error. The project is an personal home security thing.

My main goal is to detect a change between the images that I capture from pi camera(if something is added to the current image or something removed from the image) but right now my code is too sensitive. It is affected by change in background lighting, which I do not want.

I have two options in front of me, to either scrape my current logic and start a new one or improve my current logic to account for these noise(if I can call them that). I am searching for ways to improve my logic but I wanted some guidance on how to go about it.

My biggest fear being, am I wasting time kicking a dead horse or should I just look for some other algorithm to detect a change in image or should I use edge detection

```
    import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
from threading import Thread
######Function Definition########################################
def mse(imageA, imageB):
    # the 'Mean Squared Error' between the two images is the
    # sum of the squared difference between the two images;
    # NOTE: the two images must have the same dimension
    err = np.sum((imageA.astype("int") - imageB.astype("int")) ** 2)
    err /= int(imageA.shape[0] * imageA.shape[1])

    # return the MSE, the lower the error, the more "similar"
    # the two images are
    return err

def compare_images(imageA, imageB):
    # compute the mean squared error
    m = mse(imageA, imageB)
    print(m)


def capture_image():
        ##shell command to click photos
        os.system(image_args)

##original image Path variable
original_image_path= "/home/pi/Downloads/python-compare-two-images/originalimage.png"

##original_image_args is a shell command to click photos 
original_image_args="raspistill -o "+original_image_path+" -w 320 -h 240 -q 50 -t 500"
os.system(original_image_args)

##read the greyscale of the image in to the variable original_image
original_image=cv2.imread(original_image_path, 0)

##Three images
image_args="raspistill -o /home/pi/Downloads/python-compare-two-images/Test_Images/image.png -w 320 -h 240 -q 50 --nopreview -t 10 --exposure sports"
image_path="/home/pi/Downloads/python-compare-two-images/Test_Images/"
image1_name="image.png"

#created a new thread to take pictures
My_Thread=Thread(target=capture_image)

#Thread started
My_Thread.start()

flag = 0
while(True):
        if(My_Thread.isAlive()==True):
                flag=0
        else:
                flag=1
        if(flag==1):
                flag=0
                image1 = cv2.imread((image_path+image1_name), 0)
                My_Thread=Thread(target=capture_image)
                My_Thread.start()
                compare_images(original_image, image1)
```

Answer (score 0):

A first improvement is to adjust a gain to compensate for the global variation of the light. Like taking the average intensity of the two images and correcting one with the ratio of the intensities.

This can fail in case of an change of the foreground, which will influence the global average. If that change in the foreground doesn't have a too large area, you can get an estimate by robust fitting of a linear model `y = a.x`.

A worse, but unfortunately common, scenario, is when the background illumination changes in a non-uniform way. A partial solution is to try and fit a non-uniform gain model such as one obtained by bilinear interpolation between gains estimated at the corners, or a finer subdivision of the image.

Comment: So the gain in this case would be `m` in the function `compare_image()`

Comment: @ShravanSingh: not at all. Would be the ratio of the means.

Answer (score 0):

The topic of change detection is a very studied field. One of the basic options is to model each one of the pixels as a Gaussian distribution by sampling a lot of images for each pixel and calculate the mean and variance of each pixel.

For the pixels that tend to change when there is change in lighting the variance of the pixels will be bigger than the ones that don't change as much.

In order to detect movement for a certain pixel you just need to choose what is the probability you consider as an unordarinry change in the pixel value and use the Gaussain distribution you calculated to find what is the corresponding value that is considered unordarinry.

To make this solution efficient for your raspberry pi you will need to first do an "offline" calculation of the values for each pixel that will be the threshold values for which the change in the pixel value is considered movement and store them in a file and than in the "online" sage you will just compare each pixel to the calculated value.

For the "offline" stage i recommend using images that were recorder during the entire day in order to get all the variation you need per pixel. This stage of curse can be done on your computer and only the output file will be uploaded to the raspberry pi